# creating profile page

Tags: php, profile

I've made a register and login script but it also need a profile page where users can see their information. But when I click on the logged in user the information of the user (id, username, birth) don't appear. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong????

showprofiel.php

```
<?php 
include("../includes/connection.php"); 

$id = $_GET['id']; 
?> 
<html> 
<head>
<title>User</title>
</head> 
<body> 
<?php 
$qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'"; 
$resultaatQry = mysql_query($qry); 
$resultaat = mysql_fetch_array($resultaatQry); 
?> 
    id: <?=$id?>
    <br>
    username: <?=$resultaat['username']?>
    <br>
    birth: <?=$resultaat['birth']?> 
    <br>
</body> 
</html>
```

user.php

```
<?php
// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
<html>

<head>
<title>Secured Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$qry = "SELECT * 
       FROM users 
       WHERE id='".$id."'";
$resultaatQry = mysql_query($qry);
$resultaat = mysql_fetch_array($resultaatQry); 

echo("Hallo <a href='showprofiel.php?id=".$resultaat['id']."'>".$_SESSION['username']."</a>");

echo("<br>");

?>
<br>You can put your restricted information here.</p>
<a href="../nieuws/nieuwsadmin.php">+ Nieuwsadmin</a>
<br>
<a href="logout.php">+ Logout</a>

</body>
</html>
```

loginproc.php

```
<?php
// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
include('../includes/connection.php');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password'])) . "')");

// Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
    // Set username session variable
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
    // Jump to secured page
    header('Location: securedpage.php');
}
else 
{
    // Jump to login page
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

Cheers

Comment: What does appear? Anything? A white screen? The wrong details? A large notice explaining that this is wide open to SQL injection?

Comment: Possibly `short_open_tags` disabled. You didn't look at the HTML source output perhaps?

Comment: Also note that `mysql_query` is deprecated now. Take a look at PDO: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: id, username, birth appears but not with the info behind it

Answer (score 2):

If your `$id` is an integer, don't wrap it in quotes.

This:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'";
```

Should then be:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id";
```

As a side note, using `mysql_query()` is discouraged, so take a look at using [`mysqli_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or the [`PDO::query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) method.

As @Mario mentioned, make sure this works:

```
id: <?=$id?>
```

If not, try this:

```
id: <?php echo $id; ?>
```

Last, but not least, I can't say I've ever seen someone wrap an `echo` statement in parenthesis. I think a better practice would be this:

```
echo "<br>";
```

Instead of:

```
echo("<br>");
```

Comment: I replaced the things that you've said, but i still got no output. Is it possible that this isn't good?:

    echo "<a href='showprofiel.php?id=".$resultaat['id']."'>".$resultaat['username']."</a>";
When I replace .$resultaat['id']. into a number for example id=2 then it works.

Comment: On your `showprofiel.php` page, print out `$qry`. Does `$id` have a value?

Comment: If it looks right, try `echo mysql_error();` to see if you have any errors in your query.

Comment: print $qry gives: SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=

Comment: So if the ID isn't available on `showprofiel.php`, do you see it in the URL on `user.php`?

Comment: Where does `$id` come from on `user.php`?

Comment: $id = $_GET['id']; 
$qry = "SELECT * 
    FROM users 
    WHERE id=$id";
$resultaatQry = mysql_query($qry);
$resultaat = mysql_fetch_array($resultaatQry);

Comment: I don't see `$_GET['id']` in `user.php`. Print it on the screen and see if it's set.

Comment: I've printed it, but it isn't set

Comment: So there is your problem. That value has to come from somewhere. Probably should be in your `$_SESSION`

Comment: 1. User provides credentials to login. 2. PHP checks user against database. 3. User exists and provided valid password. 4. User ID is stored in `$_SESSION['id']`. 5. `user.php` uses `$_SESSION['id']` in the URL. 6. `showprofiel.php` now has access to `$_GET['id']` and you can run additional queries. (Or just keep using `$_SESSION['id']`). Note that this is very simplified, you probably want some security checks in place.

Comment: So I just have to do this right? echo "Hallo <a href='showprofiel.php?id=".$_SESSION['id']."'>".$_SESSION['username']."</a>";

Comment: If you previously stored the ID there, then yes. If the ID is already in the session, there's no need to pass it around in the URL. You have access to `$_SESSION['id']` on `showprofiel.php`, too, provided you call `session_start();`.

Comment: Am I doing it right in loginproc.php?

Comment: No, the ID has to come from the database. How can the ID be in the URL if you didn't even know who the user was before authenticating them? Take a break and *think* about your project. If you have new questions, ask a new question. This thread is completely off-topic now :)

Comment: Oké I'll do that, thanks for your help. I'm still new at php, you've probably noticed that ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not including the session in the userprofiel.php file.